# Assign same number to group of SQL result

Tags: sql, oracle11g, window-functions

How would I be able to assign a same number to N results for several groups in
an oracle query? In this case, I illustrate it in **num_per_grp**.

I have tried using row_number() and rank() group by group_no, however the results were not suit to my requirement. It turned out that every group will have 1,2 sequence number.

I've tried this :

```
|--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------|
| id     | group_no   | amount     | created_date | row_number  |
|--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------|
|      1 | aaaaa      |    10      | 1/1/2016     |  1          |
|      2 | aaaaa      |   -10      | 1/1/2016     |  2          |
|      3 | bbbbb      |    20      | 2/1/2016     |  1          |
|      4 | bbbbb      |   -20      | 2/1/2016     |  2          |
|      5 | ccccc      |    30      | 3/1/2016     |  1          |
|      6 | ccccc      |   -30      | 3/1/2016     |  2          |
|--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------|
```

Result should be like this:

```
|--------+------------+------------+-------------|
| id     | group_no   | amount     | num_per_grp |
|--------+------------+------------|-------------|
|      1 | aaaaa      |    10      |      3      |  
|      2 | aaaaa      |   -10      |      3      |
|      3 | bbbbb      |    20      |      2      |
|      4 | bbbbb      |   -20      |      2      |
|      5 | ccccc      |    30      |      1      |
|      6 | ccccc      |   -30      |      1      |
|--------+------------+------------+-------------|
```

How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: I don't understand the logic for obtain num_per_grp.. how you calculate this value ? why the group_no aaaaa -> num_per_grp 3 ... and so on.. ?

Comment: I didn't calculate the num_per_grp. It's just an example which the result should be like that. As you can see, for every group_no, they have similar num_per_grp. I just wanna obtain that number. Rank and row_number generate sequence for every record in the group